# "Whatsapp Web is open in another computer or browser" - What should I do?

Tags: whatsapp

I was using Whatsapp Web on chrome, and I got the message "*Whatsapp Web is already open in another computer or browser*".

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have more than one computer? Have you ever used it on any other computers?

Comment: @Oasiscircle No

Comment: Well I've never used WhatsApp, but you'd think because of the nature of the app there would be a "invalidate all sessions" option in the settings. Try to look for that and then change your password.

Comment: It might also be useful to others to supply how you use WhatsApp, do you only use it over web or do you use it on your phone as well? Have you recently lost or misplaced your phone? If someone had your phone would they be able to unlock it and access your WhatsApp key store?

Comment: @Oasiscircle I use Whatsapp on phone and web, and I never lost my phone. No one has ever accessed my Whatsapp physically. There's this one guy who's mad at me since yesterday and he's a dangerous hacker

Comment: From what I understand it would literally take only a few seconds of your phone being out of view to register your key-pair as trusted in another WhatsApp web instance.  Has anyone had access to your computer for even an instant? Really at this point it could be anything, intercepting a key exchange, malware on your computer, malware on your phone (looks like you're an Android programmer, old Android phones don't have the best security if you're installing lots of apps you don't trust or have a rooted phone). Don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: @Oasiscircle My laptop is new and I use iOS (So there's no such thing as spyware since I'm not jailbroken) and no one's touched my phone before. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Don't assume that you're safe from malware because you have iOS, that's a dangerous thought to have considering how many *nix kernel vulnerabilities have been coming out lately. Like I said previously, we don't have much to go on because it literally could be anything.

Comment: @Oasiscircle oh well.

Comment: This message happens also if you have whatsapp open inside the same browser in another tab or window. Please check your other tabs and windows, minimized windows etc. When in doubt restart your system to make sure that no invisible open tabs/windows could be left.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich done that already

Comment: I've taken out the unnecessary fearmongering piece and kept the factual element of your question.

Answer (score 10):

Open Whatsapp in your handset.

Go to Options named "Whatsapp Web", Click on "Logout from all computers" & then try to login again.